# Mysql: Check if user have not been logged in last 14, 60 or 120 days

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to build a system the check witch user how have not been logged in last 14, 60 or 120 days. I like to send an email if user have not been logged in for 14 days but not at the same time send email to this user for 60 and 120 days.

**Table**: user_counts the user_count to day have over 80 000 row in it.

**Column**: time is DateTime in Mysql

```
// Number of days a user have not been login
$dateCheck = array('14', '60', '120'); 

foreach ($dateCheck as $day) {        

   $userList = $wpdb->get_results('
    SELECT id, user_id 
    FROM user_counts 

    WHERE DATE(time) = "'.date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-".$day." day")).'"
      AND time != (
          SELECT MAX(time) FROM user_counts
          WHERE time < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL '.$day.' DAY)
      )
    GROUP BY user_id
  ');

}
```

Result
I get the same user_id in all 14,60 and 120 days.

Comment: is time field timestamp ?

Comment: what does this query return now?

Comment: Updated after your feedback

Comment: is there only one record for one user_id in the table? if no, then there is possibility that same user_id exists three times matching the criteria. I mean there is possibility that user_id has three records with 14 days, 60 days, 120 days.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Number of days a user have not been login
$dateCheck = array('14', '60', '160'); 

$res = $wpdb->get_results('
    SELECT id, user_id, MAX(DATE(time)) as t 
    FROM user_counts      
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING t <= "'.date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-".min($dateCheck)." day")).'"
    ORDER BY t
');

rsort($dateCheck); 
foreach ($res as $result) {
    $date = date_create($res);

    foreach ($dateCheck as $day) {

        if ($result->t == date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-".$day." day"))) {

            // Send for exempel a mail
            // check witch email temple to use by using: $day 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't faster to make this request direct in Mysql then like this?

Comment: @user2673664 Don't you need to pass these results to PHP? If you're talking about the date then yes, it's probably better.

Comment: Yes, I will send a email to this user to say "long time.. "

Comment: And this table I have right now over 80 000 row in it.

Comment: Well a single query is faster than 3 provided you're going to go through the same number of results in PHP in the end. I still don't understand what the problem is. Have you tried this and it's too slow?